# How to find select distinct values from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

How can I use find select distinct in angularJS then counting it, I'm new to mean-stack and I don't know how to use distinct method.

**Here is my table structure with sample data:**

```
donation_no:"3124"
donors_name:"Jeremy Adrian De Vera"
date:"12/26/2018"
time:"8:30"
blood_group:"B"
volume:"2"
branch:"Pasig"
```

**I already tried it using php like this but how can I do this in angular:**

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT fruits, COUNT(*) as counter FROM my_table WHERE date_tested BETWEEN '$date_from' AND '$date_to' GROUP BY fruits";
```

Here is my code for finding the values from my db

**api.js**

```
router.get('/blooddonationmanagement', function(req, res) {

    Blooddonation.find({},function(err, blooddonations) {
        res.json({ success: true, blooddonations: blooddonations });
    });   
});
```

**blooddonationCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('blooddonationControllers', [])
.controller('blooddonationCtrl', function(Blooddonation,$scope) {
    var app = this;
    function getBlooddonations() {

        Blooddonation.getUsers().then(function(data) {    
            app.blooddonations = data.data.blooddonations;  
    });
}
```

**chapters.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in blooddonationmanagement.blooddonations">
    <td>{{ person.branch}}</td>   
</tr>
```

**How can I count the distinct values then counting it from my db, Im expecting like this:**

```
branch       count
Pasig         29
Manila        16
Pasay         19
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure as well as sample data.

Comment: okay I will update my question

Comment: updated it, I'm finding distinct values for branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

**You can use:**

```
db.collection.distinct()
```

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `distinct()`

```
Blooddonation.distinct('branch',... );
```